# Why am I receiving an System.InvalidCastException when I am trying to call my ShowStatement method?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I am able to add accounts of different types through another form to the list statements which I can then add to the list box lstaccounts. However, when I select an account in my list box and press the view statement button I get that exception on the 'lblBank.Text = ShowStatement((IStatement)lstAccounts.SelectedItem);' line... any idea why this could be happening?

```
 public List<IStatement> statements;       
    private int accountCounter = 0;
    private int statementsViewed = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        statements = new List<IStatement>();           
    }

    private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstAccounts.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            lblBank.Text = ShowStatement((IStatement)lstAccounts.SelectedItem);
            statementsViewed += 1;
            lblTotal.Text = statementsViewed.ToString();
        }
    }

    private string ShowStatement(IStatement item)
    {
        String msg = "Account Number: " + item.AccountNumber + "\n" 
                    + "Name: "  + item.AccountName  + "\n" + item.PrintStatement();
        return msg;
    }

    private void btnAddAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();

        if(form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (form2.txtValue.Text == "" && form2.txtMinMonthly.Text == "")
            {
                BankAccount b = form2.GetBankAccount();
                statements.Add(b);
            }

            else if (form2.txtMinMonthly.Text == "")
            {
                InsurancePolicy i = form2.GetInsurancePolicy();
                statements.Add(i);
            }

            else
            {
                PlatinumCurrent p = form2.GetPlatinumCurrent();
                statements.Add(p);                 
            }

            foreach (IStatement os in statements)
            {
                lstAccounts.Items.Add(os.ToString());
                accountCounter += 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

The exact error I'm getting is: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'TelephoneBanking.IStatement'.'

Comment: Where is `lstAccounts` declared? What type it is? Granted that you're using `lstAccounts.Items.Add(os.ToString())` further down in the code, `lstAccounts` seems to be a collection of strings, so why are you trying to cast one of them to an `IStatement`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added it as .ToString() in your btnAddAccount_Click. Try add the item, not the item.ToString().

```
private void btnAddAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
            foreach (IStatement os in statements)
            {
                lstAccounts.Items.Add(os); // ###### removed os.ToString() ######
                accountCounter += 1;
            }
        ...
```